# silverlight image control brightness and contrast

Tags: silverlight, image

Does anyone know how to apply brightness and contrast control to an Image in silverlight 5?  Maybe using UIElement.Effect?  I don't need to modify/save the image, just change how it is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Custom Pixel Shader.  Shazzam has a contrast adjust custom pixel shader in it's pre-installed samples.  The beauty of this is that it works in both WPF and silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WriteableBitmap` as source for your image and then apply a brightness/contrast formula on every pixel of the `WriteableBitmap`.

You need to call `Invalidate()` on your bitmap instance after you have changed the pixels.